# Can't locate USB devices

Tags: debian, usb, devices, lsusb

I'm currently playing with USB to learn more about it.

I used `lsusb` to display infos about USB buses and devices of my system. Knowing that basically everything is either a file of a directory on Linux, I tryed to find the directory that lsusb reads. I Found that de pseudo filesystem called `usbdevfs` should be mountded at `/proc/bus/usb`.

However, I couldn't navigate to this directory because it was missing. Trying to grep the directorie in the result of `mount` wasn't successful either. A quick `cd / && find -name usb` lead me to the directory `/sys/bus/usb` and `/dev/bus/usb`, but nothing in `/proc`. Looking into `/sys/bus/usb/devices` only gave me symlinks to `/sys/devices/pci00[...]`.

Please note that :

- I use a Debian Buster,
- I don't have any issues with my USB devices (they're working correctly),

So, where are my USB devices ?

Comment: plug in a USB device ... type `dmesg` in a terminal ... you should see some info about the plug event

Comment: Your question/aim (where are my USB devices?) isn't very clear. Two notes: usb(dev)fs is a thing of the past and not all USB devices have a corresponding device node, for example network interfaces aren't represented by device nodes.

Answer (score 1):

To quickly find the directories and files that `lsusb` reads, simply trace the command and search for `open()` systemcalls:

```
strace lsusb 2>&1 | grep ^open
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/uevent", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/busnum", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/devnum", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/speed", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/descriptors", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
...
```

Disregard lines that end in `ENOENT` as that means the file that was attempted to be opened does not exist. Also you will notice there are a couple variations.

Read the manual page if you want to understand what the arguments to `openat()` are, use section 2 for system calls:

```
$ man 2 open
OPEN(2)                                                                                   Linux Programmer's Manual                                                                                   OPEN(2)

NAME
       open, openat, creat - open and possibly create a file

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/stat.h>
       #include <fcntl.h>
```

For info on `/proc` try `$ man 5 proc`, but I bet you are more interested now in `/sys`:

```
$ mount | grep '/sys '
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
^^^^^

$ apropos sysfs
sysfs (2)            - get filesystem type information
sysfs (5)            - a filesystem for exporting kernel objects <== you want this one

$ man 5 sysfs
SYSFS(5)                              Linux Programmer's Manual                              SYSFS(5)

NAME
       sysfs - a filesystem for exporting kernel objects

DESCRIPTION
       The  sysfs filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem which provides an interface to kernel data struc‐
       tures.  (More precisely, the files and directories in sysfs provide  a  view  of  the  kobject
       structures  defined  internally within the kernel.)  The files under sysfs provide information
       about devices, kernel modules, filesystems, and other kernel components.
```

If you are simply just looking for the device files, for accessing the usb devices, try this command:

```
$ find /dev -ls | grep usb
find: ‘/dev/vboxusb’: Permission denied
  2421522      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           60 Oct 21 17:47 /dev/usb
  2421523      0 crw-------   1 root     root     180,   0 Oct 21 17:47 /dev/usb/hiddev0
    29281      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           12 Oct 20 14:33 /dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5:1.0-video-index0 -> ../../video0
    25532      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           12 Oct 20 14:33 /dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5:1.0-video-index1 -> ../../video1
```